# Discord.py - Get context from error object

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I have a cog `test`

I have a function that is checking to see if there is an error with the command.

In this example, at the moment, if the user does not provide an argument when invoking the command in Discord, the error is printed to the console.

I want to reply to the original message (`!test`) that invoked the command with said error message.

Usually I would use `commands.Context` to do this, however with it not being a parameter in my implementation what would the best way to about this be?

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx, arg1):
        await ctx.reply(arg1)

    @test.error
    async def test_error(self, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
            # Here I want to reply
            print(error)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Test(client))
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error handlers also take `ctx`  as an argument

```py
@test.error
async def test_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        # Here I want to reply
        print(error)
```

Take a look at the [error handling introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)